# Protobuf field extension

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am new to protobuf and trying to figure out if it would be smart to define a telegram-code (which in its bitstring identifies the message type) as a message option and if yes how would you do so?

Comment: How much about protobuf do you understand about protobuf? Given that understanding are you able to show us a basic attempt at solving this problem? Finally, please do not sign your question with a "thanks".

Comment: @Seanny123 I understand the concept and can use it on a basic level. But I have difficulties with metainformation. For example, if I have an optional uint32 example = 1, I want to be able to asign it a position and bit-length. (metainformation) = { pos: 2, len: 3 }. However I do not understand how to implement such an option.